# Nesting <a> tags between <ul> and <li>

Tags: html, syntax, markup

A quick HTML question. Is it sufficient to nest a <a> tag between the <ul> and <li> tags like this:

```
<ul>
  <a href="somewhere.html">
    <li>Option 1<li>
  </a>
  <a href="somewhereElse.html">
    <li>Option 2<li>
  </a>
<ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is invalid html, why would you do so?

Comment: @RabNawaz : Because <a> is inline by default. I thought I might be able to save some lines on CSS. Bit of a silly idea now that I think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid because inline elements cannot contain block elements. Inline elements can only contain other inline elements. Block elements can contain both inline and other block elements.

The correct HTML:

```
<ul>
     <li>
          <a href="somewhere.html">Option 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a href="somewhereElse.html">Option 2</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Both `li` and `a` tags are inline by default. `ul` is block by default.
See [list of inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements) and [list of block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) for further reading

Comment: well this is self-contradictive one

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid HTML. The `<a>` should be inside the `<li>`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is correct :

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="somewhere.html">Option 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="somewhereElse.html">Option 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Beacause `a` has to be inside `li`

Answer (score 1):

Proper syntax requires that you nest the `<a>` tag inside of the `<li>`:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="somewhere.html">Option 1</a><li>
  <li><a href="somewhereElse.html">Option 2</a><li>
<ul>
```